# Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3

Tags: jquery, npm

Me apareció el siguiente error:

> Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3

Cómo puedo actualizar mi versión de jquery a una versión especifica? ya que me pide una versión mas actual. Quise cambiar el archivo `package.json` directamente pero no encuentro aparece la versión de jquery.

este es mi archivo json:

```
{
  "name": "bonafont",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "headroom.js": "^0.9.4",
    "mdbootstrap": "^4.4.3",
    "mdbreact": "^4.0.0",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.4",
    "rc-dropdown": "^2.0.1",
    "rc-menu": "^6.0.3",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-animate-on-scroll": "^1.3.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
    "react-dd-menu": "^2.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dropdown": "^1.3.2",
    "react-headrooms": "^1.0.6",
    "react-reveal": "^0.7.3",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "react-spark-scroll": "^4.0.0",
    "react-spark-scroll-gsap": "^4.0.0",
    "react-springy-parallax": "^1.0.11",
    "react-sticky": "^6.0.1",
    "react-sticky-header": "^0.1.9",
    "react-toggle-display": "^2.2.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.2.1",
    "reactstrap": "^4.8.0",
    "scrollmagic": "^2.0.5",
    "sweetalert": "^2.0.3",
    "tether": "^1.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: posiblemente no este en el package.json por eso no lo ves, tu proyecto ya carga el jquery? solo quieres actualizarlo o apenas lo vas a agregar?

Answer (score 0):

lo que podes hacer es utilizando npm utilizar la siguiente linea:

```
npm install <package>@<version>
```

En todo caso sería:

```
npm install <jquery>@<2.2.4>
```

Asegurate de eliminar la versión que tenes actualmente de jquery, instala esa versión específica, y guardala en la dependencia.
Seguro debes saber que ingresando al final el -save se guarda automáticamente en tu package.json.